# Compactifications of a product of topological space with compact space?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification

Are there any general properties or rules for a product of a topological space and compact space to admit a compactification?

I am usually assuming Hausdorff compactifications, so the original space must by Tychonoff to admit a compactification. But this is just a matter of convention I guess. So in my question, I am asking for other requirements.

Also, generally, what properties of a general topological space can imply it will have compactifications? I am aware that any topological space can have Stone-Čech and that locally compact space can have Alexandroff one-point compactification, but what about other types of compactifications?

Thank you.